# How can i fetch thumbnail or cover art from audio files in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-pub

Thumbnail or cover art of an music player is an important part. I try many audio packages from the pub.dev  but these packages do not support the thumbnail extraction or meta extraction from music files. In asset_audio_player package we can add metas externally but we could not fetch the meta from music files. My question is there is any way that i can extract the thumbnail or meta from music files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [flutter_media_metada](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_media_metadata) for this, try to restrict the null, sometimes songs has no artwork.